# How to create a Data Factory pipeline run from PowerApps/Power Automate with Pipeline Parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory, powerapps, power-automate

I need to kick off an ADF pipeline from PowerApps or PowerAutomate with various Pipeline parameters set by the end user, which is then sent into a databricks notebook.  Using the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#create-a-pipeline-run), I was able to successfully kick off my pipeline from my PowerApp, but it's not clear how to send in pipeline parameters from that documentation  or the various blogs I've read.

After running into this a while ago, I ended up calling Databricks directly via the jobs Rest API but that ended up only working for users who already have access in Databricks, [which my End Users don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714223/how-is-the-actual-request-url-generated-from-a-custom-connector-api-definition). So I'm back to trying to add ADF as a middle layer between the two.  I must be missing something somewhere, because this clearly has to be a common use case.

Comment: You can do this with an Azure function.  I've managed it before.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerAutomate, you can set your parameters in the parameters section in JSON format so something like:
{"parameter name": "parameter value"}

[image: PowerAutomate Options]

Comment: Thanks @noelle!  I was able to set this up and got it working correctly for me, but when I send to the end users it's not working.  I added them as a contributor to ADF in iam, but are you aware of other permissions they might need to use this connector from PowerApp?

Comment: Here is the error the user is getting: The client <useremail> with object id <objectid> does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/CreateRun/action' over scope '/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourcegroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/<factory>/pipelines/<pipelinename>' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Comment: And they have the 'Data Factory Contributor' role?

Comment: Forgot to come back to this, but yep I had to add them as a Data Factory Contributor

Comment: Is there any method to catch the response of "Create a pipeline run"?